# Why Jquery onclick listener doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I have found already few answers for this topic, but none of them were working for me. Simply I want to do click and scroll event. I have a text divs in nav, which should take me to next part of my site (one page site).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="strgl"><span>HOME</span></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="text">
            Some text
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

And js:

```
$('.strgl').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#text').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ldemnbp9/. You just need to ensure that the page is actually tall enough to make the content scroll vertically.

Comment: what do you see in Console? You must describe the problem in details. What you imagine and what happend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided works fine for me. Make sure you include jQuery in your scripts and then load your javascript file. Furthermore, ensure your javascript is being loaded once the entire page has loaded (as opposed to the start of the loading process).

Also, make sure there is enough whitespace to scroll down to. (to get the scrolling animation)
Here is a working example:

```js
$('.strgl').click(function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#text').offset().top
    }, 2000);
});
```

```css
header {
  padding-bottom: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="strgl"><span>HOME</span></div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div id="text">
            Some text
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

Comment: It worked. Looks like i have coppied wrong link to js from somewhere. This one works. Thank You!